# function inside a view or stored procedure so I do not need to call it

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a `View` which is being used by a `Stored Procedure` and the results from this is being put into a temp table so I can perform paging, sorting and filtering, but one of the fields is an `Int` and must be calculated via a `Function`. Now I do not want to call the function within the `View` nor the `Stored Procedure` as it would seriously harm performance. I am trying to copy the code from the `Function` into either the `View` or the `SP`. What is the best way to do it as well as how to do it as I have multiple `DECLARE` statements and calculations within the `Function`.

Example `View`:

```
Create VIEW dbo.vw_NewView
AS
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
GO
```

Example `Stored Procedure`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetStudents
AS
SELECT 
*,
(DECLARE @newInt = 2+3
IF @newInt > 8 BEGIN return 8 END
SET @newInt * 80
RETURN @newInt) 'FreshlyAddedInt'

FROM dbo.vw_NewView
```

It must be done either within the `View` or the `Stored Procedure`. Cannot call the `Function`

Comment: Which  DB You are using? Normally we do not have `Return` statement inside `Procedures`.

Comment: `MSSQL`. Does not need to have a return statement. That was just a weak example of many different things that I have tried already. I just need to create a new `field` and set the value with some calculation